# Remove div style text from body

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the 'div style' which contains text below body class?

I have tried css but I may be doing it wrong

```
<body class="home page page-id-14 page-template page-template-100-width page-template-100-width-php logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support fusion-body no-tablet-sticky-header no-mobile-sticky-header no-mobile-slidingbar no-mobile-totop layout-wide-mode mobile-menu-design-classic" data-spy="scroll">

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -3434px;">
        Find the latest ***** available across a*******sites 
        <a target="_blank"href="http://www.website.zone/">
            Site.Zone
        </a> 
        Use our complete list ......................... available online.     
    </div>
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTlI.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: A div has to be inside the body element, not before or after it. You code is highly wrong. That may be the problem.

Comment: You can use CSS, just be sure to add `!important` after each value in order to override the properties defined in the `style` attribute.

Comment: do you have access to the HTML? can you just delete `style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -3434px;"`? If you can't delete style: add `id="myUniqueId"` and from your CSS `#myUniqueId{ (where you override things)}`. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be very helpful

Comment: Thank you. Body class comes first then the div style. I entered it wrong here.

Comment: I am not familar with jfiddle but I am not sure how to identify it in css. It is a wordpress website. I have tried:.body element.style {
 display: none;
}

Comment: @Quantastical    
I am not sure how to identify it in css. It is a wordpress website. I have tried:.body element.style { display: none; } - I have attached screenshot to post

Comment: `.body` is a class selector (the period in front of it). The appropriate element selector would just be `body`

Comment: @petreli what exactly you want to achieve ? do you want to remove text that you blacked out in your picture?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

HTML Code

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; background-color:green; ">Find the latest ***** available across a*******sites <a target="_blank"href="http://www.website.zone/">Site.Zone</a> Use our complete list ......................... available online.</div>
```

Javascript code

```
document.body.children[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

it removes style attribute of first divison i tried in jsfiddle.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/Hashy/yhg37xer/)